# I can't generate MVC controllers .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

[image]

I have there my models (generated with scaffold), I want to use Colore, but I can't use it to generate my MVC

[image]

That is my DB Context

Comment: Try building the project.

Comment: @hijinxbassist It didn't work :'(

Comment: Try closing and reopening VS.

Comment: @hijinxbassist I'm using Rider, and that kind of things, I tried.

Comment: You may need to try it via command line and see if it works. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/tools/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: After building the project, add models. Then try to create a Controller. If the issue persists, for testing purposes try to delete one of the models. Build the project, and after that again add the model. Try creating a controller, and see whether it shows model. You could also try to check by creating a new project, see whether it works and show you models while creating controllers.